# How do I make javascript functions accessible to pages in a Rails 6 project using webpacker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

In a Rails project, I am trying switch from using the old Sprockets asset pipeline to using webpacker. I have set up these test files:

**app/javascript/lib/foo.js**

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo')
}
console.log('bar')
```

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```js
// some standard Rails JS requires
// ...
require('lib/foo')
```

**app/views/test/index.html**

```html
<script>
  foo()
</script>
```

And in my **layouts/application.html.erb** I have

```rb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

When I go to that page in my browser, I see "bar" logged to my console, followed by

"ReferenceError: foo is not defined"

I have tried a few different approaches to setting up my files, like using import instead of require or setting `module.exports = foo` or `export default foo` in my js file, but I haven't had any luck getting around the above error message.

So in short, how do I move javascript files from sprockets to webpacker? And if possible, how do I do so without changing my existing javascript code?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to export functions and modules as a named export from your `application.js` pack and extend the Webpack config `output` to designate the library name and target `var` (or `window` will also work).

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

environment.config.merge({
  output: {
    library: ['Packs', '[name]'], // exports to "Packs.application" from application pack
    libraryTarget: 'var',
  }
})

// app/javascript/packs/application.js
import foo from '../lib/foo'

export {
  foo
}
```

```html
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   Packs.application.foo();
 });
</script>
```

The `library` name is arbitrary. Using the `[name]` placeholder is optional but allows you to export to separate modules if you're using multiple "packs".

Comment: You mean every javascript module included in the webpack system needs to be exported in this way?

Comment: Only those that need to be explicitly referenced from outside your bundle, i.e., from the global scope.

Comment: I don't really see how that's easier than just including it with a separate `javascript_include_tag` line, but the OP was asking about webpack, so +1.

Comment: @DavidDombrowsky can `javascript_include_tag` use javascript modules?